# cos result incorrect

Tags: c, trigonometry, degrees, radians

I import "math.h".

I can use the cos function, 
but when I execute `cos(0.321139585333178)` 
the result is `0.948876`

If I use the calculator in Mac or use a normal calculator, the result is `0.999984292347418`

Can anyone help me to solve that problem?

Comment: since I consider radians the default, the right answer is 0.94887639....; trigonometric function usually take radians, but degrees versions can be easily implemented

Answer (score 19):

You're confusing degrees with [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).

[cos(0.321139585333178 degrees)](http://www.google.com/search?q=cos(0.321139585333178+degrees)) = 0.999984292

[cos(0.321139585333178 radians)](http://www.google.com/search?q=cos(0.321139585333178+radians)) = 0.948876326

- To convert from radians to degrees, multiply by 180/π.
- To convert from degrees to radians, multiply by π/180.

Comment: Backwards.  It should be "multiply by 180/π", "divide by 180/π"

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: +1 well spotted. It's amusing because I was going to work out the conversion myself but decided that there was a small risk I'd get it backwards so instead I decided to copy it from Wikipedia which is of course peer reviewed and for such a simple thing must be correct. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversions . I will be more careful in future. ;)

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: I see you have now fixed it in Wikipedia. :)

Comment: and warned the vandal, and semi-protected it. :)